# Run gem directly from git repo with bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am developing a gem to use in my rails app.
The gem is located at `/home/me/my_gem`.

If I use `gem 'my_gem', :git => '/home/me/my_gem'` bundler takes it and installs it into `~/.bundler/...` but I want the gem to be used directly from `/home/me/my_gem` so I don't have to run `bundle install` every time I do a change to the gem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need use the :path options

```
gem 'my_gem', :path => '/home/me/my_gem'
```

After that you even not need run a bundle install. Each time is your directory code used.

Comment: I know this is old, but there seems to be no current info on how to build gems which addresses this issue, which I can find.  This is not my experience.  After changing the gem-code, I can exit the rails console, restart it, and the old gem-code is used.  I have to update the gem-version, then bundle-install to get the 'new version' of the gem (with maybe just one comma changed), and only then are the changes shown.  What am I missing?